# create prefix for columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
data=structure(list(kod_nar.id = c(1L, 3L, 2L), x123 = c(0L, 0L, 0L
), x124 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), x125 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), x126 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L)), .Names = c("kod_nar.id", "x123", "x124", "x125", "x126"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I need to add suffix for each column `_1`, `_2` and so on.

That output could be

```
  kod_nar.id x123_1 x124_2 x125_3 x126_4
1          1      0      0      0      0
2          3      0      0      0      0
3          2      0      0      0      0
```

Suffixes are ranked in ascending order.

Then same for lines

```
  kod_nar.id x123_1 x124_2 x125_3 x126_4
1          1_1      0      0      0      0
2          3_2      0      0      0      0
3          2_3      0      0      0      0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `paste`? What did you try?

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:dplyr], which seems not relevant in your question. Note that what you're asking is not called a prefix but a suffix

Answer (score 3):

something like that:

```
names(data)[2:ncol(data)] <- paste(names(data)[2:ncol(data)], 2:ncol(data)-1, sep = "_")

data$kod_nar.id <- paste(data$kod_nar.id, 1:nrow(data), sep = "_")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even try this -

#### 1. Appending Suffixes in column names-

```
> names(data)[-1] <- paste0(names(data)[-1],"_",1:(ncol(data)-1))
> data
  kod_nar.id x123_1 x124_2 x125_3 x126_4
1          1      0      0      0      0
2          3      0      0      0      0
3          2      0      0      0      0
```

#### 2. Appending suffixes in id column**

```
> data.table::setDT(data)[,kod_nar.id:=paste0(kod_nar.id,"_",1:nrow(data))]
> data
   kod_nar.id x123_1 x124_2 x125_3 x126_4
1:        1_1      0      0      0      0
2:        3_2      0      0      0      0
3:        2_3      0      0      0      0
```